# Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.1

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx with android studio ,, it's working fine ,, but there is a project when i try to import it ,, i get this error

> Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to open SDK Manager and install the SDK build-tool version 22.0.1

[image]

Comment: Or just use the highest number that is installed...

Comment: Also check "Show Package Details" if you want to install several or older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the SDK Manager what is your highest Android SDK Build-tools version, and copy this version number in your project "build.gradle" file in the android/buildToolsversion property

Comment: there is no android/buildToolsversion 
this is libgdx

Comment: @Maysara In build.gradle, change the buildToolsVersion property value. I'm not sure what libgdx has to do with that